# Scala error when assigning value to array element

Tags: scala

I have the following array:

```
var visited = new Array[Boolean](n + 1)
```

I don't have experience with Scala but I believe this array is mutable because I am instantiating it with `new`.

However, when I try to assign a value to one of its elements(where `comp.node` is an integer):

```
visited[comp.node] = true;
```

I am getting the following error:

```
error: ';' expected but '=' found.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Scala, you cannot access or assign array elements using the `[]` syntax. Instead, `()` has to be used:

```
visited(comp.node) = true     // assignment - calls visited.update(comp.node, true)
val test = visited(comp.node) // access     - calls visited.apply(comp.node)
```

`[]` is solely used for type arguments:

```
val list: List[String] = List[String]()
```